# Extract ancillary parameters from maximum likelihood model in Stata

Tags: stata

In Stata while using maximum likelihood (`ml`) estimation, I can use `diparm` (in `ado` file) to display the ancillary (auxillary) parameters. But, when I used `ereturn list` I didnot see the way to extract these coefficients. Is there something like `mat list e(b)` for ancillary parameters?

```
ereturn list

scalars:
               e(rank) =  13
                  e(N) =  6378
                 e(ic) =  17
                  e(k) =  13
               e(k_eq) =  5
               e(k_dv) =  2
          e(converged) =  1
                 e(rc) =  0
          e(k_autoCns) =  0
                 e(ll) =  -7465.044032705097
         e(k_eq_model) =  1
               e(df_m) =  4
               e(chi2) =  65.60818581991281
                  e(p) =  1.91572317062e-13
              e(k_aux) =  2

macros:
                e(cmd) : "mypro"
           e(chi2type) : "Wald"
                e(opt) : "moptimize"
            e(predict) : "ml_p"
                e(vce) : "oim"
               e(user) : "mypro_ll"
           e(crittype) : "log likelihood"
          e(ml_method) : "lf"
    e(singularHmethod) : "hybrid"
          e(technique) : "nr"
              e(which) : "max"
             e(depvar) : "y1 y2"
         e(properties) : "b V"

matrices:
                  e(b) :  1 x 13
                  e(V) :  13 x 13
               e(ilog) :  1 x 20
           e(gradient) :  1 x 13
               e(ml_h) :  1 x 13
           e(ml_scale) :  1 x 13

functions:
             e(sample)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ancillary parameters are typically stored in their own "equation" in the `e(b)` matrix. See:

M.L. Buis (2011) "Stata tip 97: Getting at $\rho$s and $\sigma$s", The Stata Journal, 11(2), pp. 315-317. http://www.maartenbuis.nl/publications/sigma_rho.html

And: http://www.maartenbuis.nl/wp/p_value_3.html

Comment: Thank you very much. That was what I was actually looking for. In your paper you also mentioned the link to another paper regarding testing the constraint on boundary value. I have a parameter which takes a value between 0 and 1. If I impose a constraint of 0 or 1, Stata generates "numerical overflow Error code 1400" problem. However, if I impose constraint of 0.0002 or 0.9999, it works. I want to know whether this is acceptable approach of testing 0 or 1.

Comment: Constraints in Stata are linear equalities; inequalities are excluded. Reparameterising to logit scale is what you seek. There is a Stata FAQ on this.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. These tests typically assume a normal sampling distribution under the null hypothesis for that parameter. If you are on (or very near) the boundary than (approximately) half of that assumed sampling distribution is impossible. So, typically the correct sampling distriubtion under the null is some kind of mixture distribution. Which exact distribution you should use is not my specialty, so you'll need to ask somebody else.

Comment: I assume that the other article you are refering to is: Gutierrez, R., S. Carter, and D. M. Drukker. 2001. On boundary-value likelihood-ratio tests. Stata Technical Bulletin, 60: 15–18. Notice that it is freely availalbe, so there is no need to speculate about its content: http://www.stata-press.com/journals/stbcontents/stb60.pdf